# jquery toggle between ul li many to many child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check my html code bellow. There i want if Level1 clicked it will hide all of its child `ul` and `li` of level1 then if clicked it back it will show again i mean toggle between them. Like this way if i click Level2 it will only toggle its child `ul` and `li` as like Level1. But as per my current first step i am trying to toggle on Level1 but the issue it once i click Level1 its totally getting hidden and not come back again. Anyone can tell me how can i achieve this?

here is my [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/801576/)

Html:

```
<ul>
 <li class="l1">
 <a href="#">Level1</a>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Level2</a>
          <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Level2 child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level2 child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level2 child</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
 <li class="l1">
 <a href="#">Level1</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $('.l1').on('click',function(){

    $(this).toggle();
    //alert("clicked");

  });


 });
```

Comment: Solution should be fairly obvious...toggle the sub menu not the whole `<li>`

Comment: Can u answer? Also i need to toggle between child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're facing is that you're selecting the whole element rather than just it's children. Check out the following JS and let me know if that's what you're looking for

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.l1').on('click',function() {
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: this works but can u tell me also how to do it with level2?

Comment: I would try something like [this](https://jsbin.com/matopikaso/edit?html,js,console,output)